# Deserialize XML with multiple VARYING namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize XML reports. 
This is the class that gets generated from the XML (class is fine). 
However, the namespaces do **vary** between SQL-server versions.

e.g. the report namespace which is

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"
```

in the below example could also be

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition"
```

etc.

Also I'm presuming this namespace can vary

```
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
```

How can I deserialize XML with varying namespace (without creating a separate class for every possible namespace) ?

This is my XML-class:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Xml2CSharp 
{
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSource",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class DataSource
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSourceReference",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string DataSourceReference { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "SecurityType",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
       public string SecurityType { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSourceID",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
       public string DataSourceID { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSources",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class DataSources
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSource",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "QueryParameter",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class QueryParameter
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Value { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "QueryParameters",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class QueryParameters
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "QueryParameter",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public List<QueryParameter> QueryParameter { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Query",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class Query
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSourceName",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string DataSourceName { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "QueryParameters",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public QueryParameters QueryParameters { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "CommandType",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string CommandType { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "CommandText",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string CommandText { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Timeout",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Timeout { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "UseGenericDesigner",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
       public string UseGenericDesigner { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Field",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class Field
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataField",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string DataField { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "TypeName",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
       public string TypeName { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fields",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class Fields
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Field",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public List<Field> Field { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSet",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class DataSet
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Query",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public Query Query { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fields",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public Fields Fields { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSets",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class DataSets
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSet",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public List<DataSet> DataSet { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Values",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class Values
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Value",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Value { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DefaultValue",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class DefaultValue
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Values",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public Values Values { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSetReference",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public DataSetReference DataSetReference { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReportParameter",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class ReportParameter
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataType",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string DataType { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DefaultValue",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public DefaultValue DefaultValue { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Prompt",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Prompt { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Hidden",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Hidden { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValidValues",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public ValidValues ValidValues { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DataSetReference",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class DataSetReference
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSetName",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string DataSetName { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ValueField",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string ValueField { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "LabelField",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string LabelField { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ValidValues",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class ValidValues
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSetReference",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public DataSetReference DataSetReference { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReportParameters",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class ReportParameters
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReportParameter",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public List<ReportParameter> ReportParameter { get; set; }
   }

   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Report",
       Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
   public class Report
   {
       [XmlElement(ElementName = "AutoRefresh",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string AutoRefresh { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSources",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public DataSources DataSources { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "DataSets",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public DataSets DataSets { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReportParameters",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public ReportParameters ReportParameters { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Code { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "Language",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string Language { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ConsumeContainerWhitespace",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition")]
       public string ConsumeContainerWhitespace { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReportUnitType",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
       public string ReportUnitType { get; set; }

       [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReportID",
           Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")]
       public string ReportID { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
       public string Xmlns { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "rd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
       public string Rd { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use serialization.  I usually use Xml Linq which you can extract the namespace from the elements dynamically.

Comment: @jdweng: Nah, then I have to "parse" the elements manually, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Stefan's solution has to be set at compilation time while mine is dynamic and will work with any URL.

Comment: @jdweng: First, I use deserialization, not serialization. Also, further processing is going on - and the format switching is neither easy nor trivial - that's why the result needs to be deserialized - I don't want to parse it myselfs. Xml Linq is not a replacement for deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about reading the namespace, then replacing it in text, and then deserialize from the replaced text ? 
Since you have a report, the chances of the namespace-text appearing somewhere in content should be remote...

```
public RdlReader OpenXml(string xml)
{
    System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    document.XmlResolver = null;
    document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    document.LoadXml(xml);

    string default_namespace = Xml2CSharp.Report.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE;
    string designer_namespace = Xml2CSharp.Report.DESIGNER_NAMESPACE;

    if (document.DocumentElement.HasAttribute("xmlns"))
        default_namespace = document.DocumentElement.Attributes["xmlns"].Value;

    if (document.DocumentElement.HasAttribute("xmlns:rd"))
        designer_namespace = document.DocumentElement.Attributes["xmlns:rd"].Value;

    this.m_xml = xml
        .Replace(default_namespace, Xml2CSharp.Report.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)
        .Replace(designer_namespace, Xml2CSharp.Report.DESIGNER_NAMESPACE);

    document = null;


    document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    document.XmlResolver = null;
    document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    document.LoadXml(this.m_xml);


    Xml2CSharp.Report rep = Tools.XML.Serialization.DeserializeXmlFromString<Xml2CSharp.Report>(this.m_xml);
    System.Console.WriteLine(rep);

    this.m_document = document;
    this.m_nsmgr = GetReportNamespaceManager(this.m_document);

    return this;
}
```

Like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Report",
    Namespace = Report.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)]
public class Report
{
    public const string DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition";
    public const string DESIGNER_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner";
    [...]
```

Comment: This solution is not dynamic.  It has to be set at compilation time.

Comment: @jdweng: Wrong, because it dynamically replaces the 2 namespaces IN THE XML-STRING to the compiled default namespace which is constant (non-dynamic) - this works at runtime - it's not a compile-time feature. But it's a hack - it's a reversal of the problem - making the XML's namespaces the same as the serializer's.

Comment: Looks like to me the property on the class does not get changed at run time :  Namespace = Report.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE

Comment: @jdweng: Yea, the property doesn't get changed. But the XML is changed to match the compiled properties: this.m_xml = xml
        .Replace(default_namespace, Xml2CSharp.Report.DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)
        .Replace(designer_namespace, Xml2CSharp.Report.DESIGNER_NAMESPACE); that's why it works.

Comment: This is a bad solution; this breaks xml digital signature as soon as you touch anything in the xml.